# OpenAPI Authentication issues - signature calculation

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script

I am working on a project for an integration with [HikCentral Professional OpenAPI](https://tpp.hikvision.com/tpp/HCPIntegration).

I want to send a couple of requests to the API but I am unable to properly authenticate.

I have created partner appKey and appSecret but based on the documentation I have to also calculate X-CA-Signature with HmacSHA-256 and base64.

I am trying to do this through postman at the moment but I haven't had much luck with the pre-request scripts.

I used the following to generate the signature in JS inside postman in order to set it as a variable:

```
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("secret-key").toString();
pm.environment.set("appSignature", "signature");
```

The above doesn't work, (probably because it is missing the base64 encoding?) although CryptoJS is a postman built-in library.

I also tried to generate the signature with Python on a separate script:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

secret = "secret-key"

hashed = hmac.new(secret.encode(), b"", hashlib.sha256)
digest = hashed.digest()
base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(digest).decode()

print(base64_encoded)
```

I have set the above encoded signature manually as a value in the headers of postman but I get timeouts in the response.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone interested, I was able to resolve the issue by opening a support ticket to HikVision. They provided a PDF with detailed instructions on how to calculate the signature in Postman and they even provided a postman collection with examples.

In general you should use the following as a spre-req script in order to properly generate the signature.

```
var appSecret = "appSecret";
var textToSign = "POST"+"\n"+"application/json"+"\n"+"application/json;charset=UTF-8"+"\n"+"/artemis/api/resource/v1/vehicle/vehicleList";
console.log(textToSign);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(textToSign, appSecret);
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
pm.environment.set("SIGNATURE", signature);
```

If anyone ever needs help again with this, ping me and I can provide all the relevant files and postman collection.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your answer that your server is hosted on 10.19.133.55, which is an [IP address reserved for private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses). Since Postman runs in the cloud, it will never be able to access your local network directly.

There are some workarounds to test locally, like running postman's [local enterprise application](https://learning.postman.com/docs/administration/managing-enterprise-deployment/#deploying-the-postman-enterprise-app), but I would recommend using a tool like [cURL](https://curl.se/docs/) to test locally. To build whatever integration/application your working on, I'd reccomend python's [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library or node.js's [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) api.

Be careful of where your code is running. If you're creating a web app, javascript will likely run in the browser, so you would need some kind of gateway to access the api on a local server.

Comment: The IP you see is actually from the example in the documentation. I provided the image to support my question and to show the signature calculation approach from HikCentral. This is not my IP, all my tests are actually run locally.

Comment: @vsapountzis do you have the error message that the request results in, or does it fail silently?